# How to delete file names date is older than 30 days

Tags: shell-script

If I have a files with their filenames as the date they were created:

```
temp_30042019
temp_15042019
temp_10042021
temp_20022020
temp_21102022
temp_22102022
temp_01112022
```

How would I compare the files names against todays current date

```bash
$ echo `date +"%d%m%Y"`
#output:
01112022
```

If the file names date is older than 30 days then delete it. I would expect to end up with

```
temp_21102022
temp_22102022
temp_01112022
```

Comment: No need to use **echo `date +"%d%m%Y"`**, you can just use: `date +"%d%m%Y"`

Answer (score 1):

Using a `bash` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

older30days=$(date --date 'now - 30 days' '+%Y-%m-%d')

echo Checking files before $older30days

for file in ./temp_*; do
   cdate="$(echo ${file#*_} | awk -v FS='' -v OFS='-' '{print $5$6$7$8,$3$4,$1$2}')"

   if [[ $cdate < $older30days ]]; then
      echo "Removing file: " $file
      rm $file
   fi
done
```

You do not need to print with `echo` in the code above but it should be useful to understand what is actually happening in your script.

Using `echo ${file#*_} | awk -v FS='' -v OFS='-' '{print $5$6$7$8,$3$4,$1$2}` I'm parsing the date of your filenames into a valid date so I will be able to compare using an `if` condition. For example, having this filename:

```
temp_15042019
```

With the code above I'm parsing it into:

```
2019-04-15 #YYYY-MM-DD
```